# Origen de la expresión "¡A mí, plin!"

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones, expresiones-fijas

El DRAE recoge en el epígrafe [**plin**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TPw0Qw0) unicamente:

> Tb. **plim**.
>
> a mí, a ti, etc., plin
>
> 1. exprs. coloqs. U. para indicar que a algo no se le da ninguna importancia.

Por lo que he podido averiguar, parece que las palabras (y la expresión) no entraron en el DRAE hasta **2001**, lo que me llama la atención al ser una expresión que debía ser muy conocida casi 100 años antes, ya que según el  CORDE ["**A mi plin**"](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=4&tipo2=0&iniItem=25&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=101016%5C011%5CC000O10102016113723459.1172.1168&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20plin%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&marcas=0) ya aparece en 1916 en Mexico en la novela *Los de abajo*, de Mariano Azuela, en 1917 en *Los neutrales* de Arniches, o en 1918 en *La venganza de Don Mendo* de Muñoz Seca, etc.
[**"A mi plim"**](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll), en cambio, sólo figura en 3 ocasiones muy posteriores (años 1932, 1939 y 1972).

Sobre su etimología he podido encontrar en [frases de origen militar](http://es.slideshare.net/josedemariapintopinto/frases-de-origen-militar-51865754):

> 9. “A MI PLIN” Me importa muy poco.
> 10. El General Prim, personaje popular y de gran prestigio, estaba hacia 1868 implicado en la lucha política. Cuando a alguien se le preguntaba “¿A quién prefieres para sustituir a Isabel II?", la respuesta común y evasiva, como queriendo decir que les llegaba con el General, era: “A mi, Prim”.

y [aquí](https://sites.google.com/site/darlealalengua/assignments/%C2%A1amiplin):

> Al parecer, el origen de esta expresión tiene relación con el general Juan Prim (1818-1870), antes de la Revolución de 1868, llamada La Gloriosa. Algunos autores suponen que la expresión "A mí, plin" sería una corrupción de "A mí, Prim", lo cual se diría cuando a uno le preguntaran por sus aficiones políticas. Otros autores prefieren negar este origen y sostienen que es una de las muchas frases elaboradas en función de su sonido o sin ningún significado en absoluto.

[Aquí](http://www.esacademic.com/dic.nsf/sp_sp_dichos_refranes/77/%C2%A1a) recogen:

> Es posible que esta expresión, popularizada por una marca de colchones, y que sugiere desdén o desinterés de alguien hacia algo, sea una deformación de <<¡A mí, Prim!>>, aunque esta última expresión significaba precisamente lo contrario: interés hacia alguien. Circulan diversas interpretaciones sobre su origen, pero todas coinciden en señalar a diversas mujeres como inventoras del dicho y en señalar al general Antonio Prim (1814-1870), paradigma de apostura en su tiempo, como destinatario de lo que en sus orígenes fue un piropo.

Ninguna de las hipótesis me acaba de convencer. ¿Alguien tiene alguna otra? ¿Cómo es que tardó tanto en entrar en el DRAE?

Comment: Buscando "plin" en el CORDE sale una referencia a [este texto](https://books.google.es/books?id=b7iaAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=sacristan+joz+plin&source=bl&ots=4wxOi4Ns5N&sig=FSRMna8JNcQybbUEbcojOTU7-Hg&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjesYaGktDPAhXH0xQKHRk6Ag0Q6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=sacristan%20joz%20plin&f=false) de 1924, en el que "plin" se usa como onomatopeya. Puede que el origen sea onomatopéyico simplemente.

Comment: Existe un cuplé estrenado por Luisa Rubí en 1906 y compuesto por Eduardo Montesinos titulado "A mí, Plin!", y basado en la frase de La Revoltosa.

Comment: Donde en el mundo se usa esa frase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extraído de *[El porqué de los dichos](http://static0.planetadelibros.com/libros_contenido_extra/31/30011_El_porque_de_los_dichos.pdf)*, de José María Iribarren (Barcelona, 2013):

> El ¡A mí, Prim!, en el sentido de «A mí, qué!», «¡A mí qué se me da!», aparece
>   en el libreto de la famosa zarzuela de López Silva y Fernández Shaw titulada *La Revoltosa*, estrenada en Madrid el año 1897. Uno de los personajes dice: ¡A mí, Prim! (frase que quedó desde entonces como «timo» de chulería), y otro le responde: «Y a mí, Frascuelo».

He encontrado también una referencia en [un relato en el diario El Día](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/pdf.raw?query=id:0002415691&lang=en&log=00000000-00000-00001/), fechado en 1900:

> Y ahora dime: ¿cómo andas de remordimientos? ¿Te has decidido á exclamar como
>   en la famosa zarzuela: «¡á mí, Prim!»? Dímelo, para que yo pueda contestar:
>   «¡á mí, Frascuelo!».

La frase en la zarzuela mencionada proviene de una historia que tiene que ver con tu tercera hipótesis, la de Antonio Prim, paradigma de apostura. Lo recoge el libro mencionado al principio, el cual a su vez lo extracta de otro libro titulado *Limpia y fija* (Madrid, 1922):

> «En los días en que Prim estaba en el ápice de su popularidad, entraba por
>   Recoletos, un domingo por la tarde, una real moza de servir, en la amartelada
>   compañía de un ramplón, desmedrado y feísimo *sorche*.
>
> »Tres o cuatro sargentos, al cruzarse con la desigual pareja, se liaron a piropear a la bella moza:
>
> »—¡Vaya una jembra juncal! ¡Viva la gracia y viva el salero, y vivan sus
>   papás de usté, y muera el mal gusto que usté tiene! Pero, gloria, ¿de dónde
>   acá hacen los ángeles tan buenas migas con los demonios?
>
> »La sandunguera moza, lanzando dos miradas: una de sumo desdén a los
>   sargentos guapos y otra de hondo cariño al feísimo *sorche*, dijo con altivo
>   donaire:
>
> »—Pa mí..., ¡Prim!
>
> »Oyó la frase alguna gente, y de boca en boca se ha ido transformando
>   (degenerando, mejor dicho) hasta caer en la rastrera locución con que ahora
>   "ilustramos" y "decoramos" el lenguaje familiar, estropeándola en su primitivo
>   y gracioso significado: el de manifestar nuestro amoroso interés por algo
>   que incomprensiblemente zahieren los demás»

Parece que "plin" sería una corrupción de "Prim", pues. Sobre lo de que no hubiera aparecido antes en el diccionario, se me ocurren algunas hipótesis:

1. Que el uso fuese muy localizado en una región (Madrid, en este caso) durante un tiempo antes de que su uso se extendiera. Sin embargo, en el DRAE vemos a veces que añaden palabras aunque su uso se restrinja a una única región.
2. Que durante mucho tiempo la expresión se usara en el habla más que en la escritura. Hay que tener en cuenta que el DRAE recoge el uso de las palabras en la escritura, y no en la expresión oral. Tú mismo has dicho que no hay muchas apariciones de la expresión en el CORDE.

Answer (score 2):

No tienen nada que ver con Prim. La frase se origina en los años 40 con el comediante puertorriqueño Ramón Del Rivero (Diplo). "Plin" era un postre similar al flan de hoy día. En una película un mozo de restaurante le pregunta a Diplo qué querían de postre. Él contesta:

> A mí plin y a la Madama dulce de coco.

Eso es una versión, la otra es que Diplo quiso decir:

> A mí cualquier cosa y a la Dama dulce de coco.

Y si tienen otra explicación, ¡a mí, plin!

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Sin duda la televisión es un potente motor de difusión de frases y expresiones habladas, y podría ser una respuesta convincente, pero no explica por qué entonces hay casos escritos de la expresión a principios del siglo XX cuando aún no existía la televisión. Por otro lado, tu respuesta es solo tu opinión, no está documentada de ninguna forma. ¿Tienes algo en lo que basarte? Te animamos a que busques documentación que apoye tu teoría y la enlaces aquí para que podamos contrastarla. Es la filosofía del sitio: ¡grandes respuestas a grandes preguntas!